"Criminals" are put in isolated prison cells until they "die," but they actually get a new personality instead
A bit more info: People who are "criminals" or similar are put in isolated cells. They stay there until they "die," but they don't actually die. They become another person, or whatever happens to them when they "die" - might involve a new body, or a new personality for the body you already have. The protagonist was "arrested" and put in a cell, but unlike the others, he knew he specifically was going to actually die. The other prisoners are confused about why he's so anxious/upset.
My husband read this around 1985, give or take a few years. He's not sure whether it was a short story or a novel. If a story, it would've been in a collection rather than a magazine.
Thanks in advance for any help you can provide us in finding this!

Thank you both! The Laumer story seems to be a better match, so we're going to look further into that one. I'll let you know, and I appreciate it!

A Trace of Memory by Keith Laumer
has a scene that matches this. The natives of Vallon, the planet where the second part of the story takes place, do not die of old age; instead, they undergo the Change: Their bodies renew themselves to the age of a young adult. Sadly the Change also means they lose all memories of their previous life, so they become a completely new person.
When Legion, the protagonist of "A Trace of Memory", is imprisoned on Vallon, his jailors expect to welcome a new citizen someday, but as earth-born human, Legion of course knows the only thing they will find is a heap of bones:

I forced myself to relax, breathe deep. Being immured wasn't the same as being buried alive--not exactly. This was the method these latter-day Vallonians had figured out to end a man's life effectively ... without ending all his lives. They figured to keep me neatly packaged here until my next Change, thus acquiring another healthy newman for the kitchen or the stables. They didn't know the only Change that would happen to me was death.

The book came out 1963, which matches your husband reading it in 1985. What doesn't match: There are no other prisoners at that place and time:

The bread man had stopped at one cell only -- mine. Foster wasn't here.

In fact there is no reaction at all to his excitement:

"Hey!" I yelled, "listen to me! I'll die in here. I'm not like the rest of you; I won't go through a Change. I'll rot here till I die...!"
I listened. The silence was absolute.
"Answer me!" I screamed. "You're making a mistake...!"
I gave up when my throat got raw. The people who dropped the bread through the little holes to the prisoners had heard a lot of yelling in their time. They didn't listen any more.

As I found in this answer, the story is freely available in several formats at Project Gutenberg.

This bears some similarity to The Penal Cluster by Randall Garrett writing as Ivar Jorgensen, which is a pen name for a number of well known authors. It is a novella and was first published in Amazing Stories in 1957. You can read it for free at Project Gutenberg.
In this story, the world (Earth) has seen a rise of the supernormal deviants, who are high-powered telepaths that use their telepathy to control normal people to commit crimes for them. The general public sees these telepaths as a great threat and they are exiled to titular cluster of asteroids, where they are imprisoned, immobile and drugged for as long as they live. However, what the general public don't know, is that telepaths are on the rise and there are normal (i.e. not deviant) ones out there who use their powers for good. The narrator/main character is one such, he uses his power to find/track the deviants, under the auspices of a police force.
Eventually he is identified as a telepath and sentenced to the penal asteroids, where he wakes up and is converted into a new, more powerful form with the help of other telepaths also on the asteroids. Another newly sentenced telepath goes insane instead of converting. The main character is then returned to earth under a new identity. It turns out this is all part of a plan by senior telepaths in society to help weed out deviant telepaths in the world as telepaths are becoming more and more common and will soon outnumber normal people.

Thank you both so much! I'll run these by my husband tomorrow.
